# How to create a XRCed generated scrolled window within aui managed application

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I try to load panels created with XRCed in a AUI frame. The panels are sometimes larger than the pane and need scrollbars, so I enclosed the content inside a scrolled window. The panel is created but I can not get the scrollbars working. With the scroled window encloed within a sizer, I was expecting this to work as stated in the documentation.
I use the XRCed generated Python code to load the panel.
I am using wxPython version 2.8.12.1 on Windows 7, XRCed version 0.2.0-8 and Python 2.7.

```
import wx
from wx import aui
from example_xrc import xrcexample

class TopWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._mgr = aui.AuiManager()
        self._mgr.SetManagedWindow(self)
        self._mgr.AddPane(self.create_panel_from_xrc(), aui.AuiPaneInfo().
                          Name("name1").Caption("caption1").CenterPane())
        self._mgr.AddPane(self.create_textctrl(), aui.AuiPaneInfo().
                          Name("name2").Caption("caption2").Bottom())
        self._mgr.GetPane("nam1").Show().Center().Layer(0).Row(0).Position(0)
        self._mgr.GetPane("name2").Show().Bottom().Layer(0).Row(0).Position(0)
        self._mgr.Update()

    def create_textctrl(self):
        text = "This is text box"
        return wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, text, wx.Point(0, 0), wx.Size(150, 90),
                           wx.NO_BORDER | wx.TE_MULTILINE)

    def create_panel_from_xrc(self):
        return xrcexample(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    top_window = TopWindow(None, -1, "")
    top_window.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

The following code is the stripped down code generated by XRCed. The XRC is embedded.

```
import wx
import wx.xrc as xrc
__res = None

def get_resources():
    global __res
    if __res == None:
        __init_resources()
    return __res

class xrcexample(wx.Panel):
    def PreCreate(self, pre):
        pass

    def __init__(self, parent):
        pre = wx.PrePanel()
        self.PreCreate(pre)
        get_resources().LoadOnPanel(pre, parent, "example")
        self.PostCreate(pre)

# ------------------------ Resource data ----------------------
def __init_resources():
    global __res
    __res = xrc.EmptyXmlResource()
    wx.FileSystem.AddHandler(wx.MemoryFSHandler())
    example_xrc = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" ?><resource>
  <object class="wxPanel" name="example">
    <style>wxTAB_TRAVERSAL</style>
    <object class="wxBoxSizer">
      <orient>wxVERTICAL</orient>
      <object class="sizeritem">
        <object class="wxScrolledWindow" name="scrolled_window">
          <object class="wxFlexGridSizer">
            <rows>0</rows>
            <cols>2</cols>
            <object class="sizeritem">
              <object class="wxStaticText">
                <label>LABEL</label>
              </object>
            </object>
            <object class="sizeritem">
              <object class="wxTextCtrl"/>
            </object>
... # repeat label / textctrl many times ...
          </object>
        </object>
      </object>
    </object>
  </object>
</resource>'''
    wx.MemoryFSHandler.AddFile('XRC/example/example_xrc', example_xrc)
    __res.Load('memory:XRC/example/example_xrc')
```